# How to pass nested arguments from one ant target to another

Tags: ant, build

How to pass nested arguments from one ant target to another?

I need to pass a variable number of nested elements from one target to another.

I have a common file with all of my standard build tasks that's included in all of my projects.
I am adding a new custom task that takes a variable number of nested arguments
As a standard, all ant calls are made through the common file to ensure consistency of build style and logging.
Thus the new custom task and its nested child will be defined in the common script.

The project build script looks like this

```
<target name="projectBuild">
  ...
  <ant target="_newFooTaskWrapper" antfile="commonFile">
    <property name="_arg1" value="hello"/>
    <property name="_arg2" value="world"/>
    <nestedArg value="qux"/>
    <nestedArg value="baaz"/>
     ...
    <nestedArg value="AAAAA"/>
  </ant>
  ...
</target>
```

The common script looks like this:

```
<target name ="_newFooTaskWrapper">
   <echo message="Target _newFooTaskWrapper in project ${ant.project.name} from base directory ${basedir}"/>
   <echo message="arg1 = ${_arg1}"/>
   <echo message="arg2 = ${_arg2}"/>

  <taskdef name="newFooTask" classname="org.foo.NewFooTask"/>
  <typedef name="nestedArg" classname="org.foo.NewFooTask$NestedArg"/>

  <newFooTask arg1="${_arg1}" arg2="${_arg2}">
    <nestedArg value="qux"/>
    <nestedArg value="baaz"/>
     ...
    <nestedArg value="AAAAA"/>
 </newFooTask>
```

Obviously, this isn't right.  My question is, what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to pass a variable number of nested elements from one target to another.

For "varible", I assume you mean you don't know the exact number of the nested elements you want to pass to the task, so what you want is something like `method(Object param...)` in java, is it?

It's not a good idea to try such a way. Ant is not a scripting language but a build tool. It provides limited "scripting" possibilities.

However, you can try it in the following two ways:

1, If your nested element is just in the form of `<elementName value="xx" />`, you don't need anything complicated. Just pass another property containing a comma seperated list of the values, and process the list in your custom ant task. It's easy for Java to split the property into a list and process it.

2, If your nested element may be more complicated... maybe you can try `reference`:

Make a type `fooTaskParams` which can be referenced via an id:

```
<fooTaskParams id="_foo_task_params">
    <nestedArg value="qux"/>
    <nestedArg value="baaz"/>
     ...
    <nestedArg value="AAAAA"/>
</fooTaskParams>
```

and pass the reference to the other build file:

```
<ant target="_newFooTaskWrapper" antfile="commonFile">
    <property name="_arg1" value="hello"/>
    <property name="_arg2" value="world"/>
    <reference refid="_foo_task_params"/>
</ant>
```

and then make your task to be able to process the reference:

```
<newFooTask arg1="${_arg1}" arg2="${_arg2}" paramRefId="_foo_task_params" />
```

You may need to take care of reference override, or make your task able to process the ref as well as taking nested elements.

Read ant's manual about [`<ant>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) and [`<typedef>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html) for more about this approach, and refer to SO Q&As like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514821/custom-ant-types-with-reference-result-in-empty-class) when you encount any problem.

Comment: Yes, passing as a reference worked.  One note, to get this to work correctly, I had to use classloader references.  That is, I had to declare a classloaderref attribute in the project's build script typedef line, then pass the reference in the <ant> call along with the properties, and then use that classloaderref in the taskdef and typedef calls in the common script.

Comment: @MicahTessler Thanks for the additional info. Acutally I never tried this before, so your information will be useful for other people searching for solutions to similar questions.